# This SVG animation does not seem to want to have a smooth transition, how do i solve this?

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

I'am trying to make a SVG animation using the SMIL  declaration, but instead of getting a smooth transition between two paths, i get a imediate transition from one to the other, and it seems to be independent of the time for the duration of the animation. Can someone help me with this, I would really like to make this a smooth transition, and preferably in SMIL because of file size.

Here is the code:

```html
<svg
   width="130mm"
   height="130mm"
   viewBox="0 0 130 130">
    <path d="M29.392899 105.03816999999998C31.388397 106.80194999999998 33.532246 108.42680000000001 35.757774 109.88056 37.428773 110.97210000000001 39.145833 111.96722 40.880677 112.85228000000001L35.993332 109.52785Z" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#070707">
        <animate dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" values="M29.392899 105.03816999999998C31.388397 106.80194999999998 33.532246 108.42680000000001 35.757774 109.88056 37.428773 110.97210000000001 39.145833 111.96722 40.880677 112.85228000000001L35.993332 109.52785Z;M27.107598 102.89224000000002C31.114479 106.89909999999998 36.14859 110.43669 41.10393 112.96472999999997L30.967228 104.24995000000001 21.295187 95.93468999999999C23.088927 98.51334000000003 24.941479 100.72611999999998 27.107598 102.89224000000002Z;M29.392899 105.03816999999998C31.388397 106.80194999999998 33.532246 108.42680000000001 35.757774 109.88056 37.428773 110.97210000000001 39.145833 111.96722 40.880677 112.85228000000001L35.993332 109.52785Z" fill="freeze"
          calcMode="spline"
          keySplines="0.1 0 0.51 1; 0.61 0.01 0.89 1">
   </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: You need the same number and type of path commands in the same order each time. Do you have that? The animate path looks longer to me at first glance.

Comment: That is because in the animate path I have to put te coordinats of the initial path ; the coordinates of the final path; and the coordinates of the initial path again, for it to even animate.

Answer (score 2):

As Robert said, you need the same number and type of path commands in the same order for each animated value. This is something that editing in a grafical UI is only partially helpfull for. In your case it may show you two line segments and two cubic Beziers in the same order - but that is not enough: the paths **must**  have some properties most GUIs don't show

- the (topologically) same start point,
- the same direction,
- and, for closed paths, you must have the same way the last point is written: either you repeat the starting point as the end point all the time, or you leave it off and close the path implicitely all the time.

In short: there is no way around *reading* the path commands.

Your first path is (rounded to sane values and repeating all path commands for clarity)

```
M 29.3929,105.038
C 31.3884,106.802 33.5322,108.427 35.7578,109.881
C 37.4288,110.972 39.1458,111.967 40.8807,112.852
L 35.9933,109.528
Z
```

while the second path was

```
M 27.1076,102.892
C 31.1145,106.899 36.1486,110.437 41.1039,112.965
L 30.9672,104.25
L 21.2952,95.9347
C 23.0889,98.5133 24.9415,100.726 27.1076,102.892
Z
```

Its fourth point (at the end of the second L command) must be the starting point, then go on with the fifth/first (identical), second, third, then close the path implicetly with the Z command.

```
M 21.2952,95.9347
C 23.0889,98.5133 24.9415,100.726 27.1076,102.892
C 31.1145,106.899 36.1486,110.437 41.1039,112.965
L 30.9672,104.25
Z
```